# Método matches() para validar se string contém somente números

Tags: java, regex

Já li alguns artigos sobre o método `matches()` e realmente não entendi.

Nesse código retornaria `false` pois estou usando uma variável e o método leu o nome da variável e não o valor referenciado por ela.

```java
String seq ="7865";
boolean Numeros = "seq".matches("\\d"); 
System.out.println("Possui números? "+Numeros);
```

Neste outro retornaria `true` pois o próprio número "chama" o método e somente tem um número. Quando tem mais de 1 número retorna false.

```java
boolean Numeros = "1".matches("\\d"); 
System.out.println("Possui números? "+Numeros);
```

Alguém poderia me explicar qual a função desse método? Estou procurando algum método para usar em validação de um CPF. Para receber somente números. Está difícil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro código não funciona porque `"seq"` (entre aspas) é uma `String` que contém o texto "seq", e não tem nada a ver com a variável `seq`.

Ou seja, `"seq".matches("\\d")` está verificando se a `String` (o texto) `"seq"` contém um número. Mas como esta `String` só tem letras (`s`, `e` e `q`), o retorno é `false`.

Se quer verificar o conteúdo da variável `seq`, retire as aspas e use a própria variável diretamente:

```
String seq ="7865";
boolean numeros = seq.matches("\\d"); // <-- repare que seq está sem as aspas
System.out.println("Possui números? " + numeros);
```

**Mas o código acima ainda vai retornar `false`**, porque o [método `matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) verifica se a `String` inteira corresponde à regex. Como a regex é `\\d`, ela só verifica se a `String` contém um dígito (exatamente um, por isso o segundo código com `"1".matches("\\d")` funciona).

Enfim, se quer validar que a `String` inteira só tem números do início ao fim, use:

```
boolean numeros = seq.matches("^\\d+$");
```

Agora temos os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que indica "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, a regex verifica se a `String` só tem um ou mais dígitos do início ao fim.

Você também poderia colocar quantidades específicas, se quiser. Exemplos:

- `\\d{11}`: exatamente 11 dígitos
- `\\d{4,11}`: no mínimo 4, no máximo 11 dígitos
- `\\d{4,}`: no mínimo 4 dígitos, sem limite máximo

Ajuste os valores para o que você precisar.

---

Mas como você disse que quer validar CPF, regex não é a melhor solução. Expressões regulares sempre trabalham com texto, e mesmo dígitos são tratados como meros caracteres, sem levar em conta o seu valor numérico. A regex só vai verificar se a string possui apenas dígitos, mas validação de CPF também inclui cálculos para checar os dígitos verificadores, e isso é [bem mais fácil fazer sem regex](https://www.google.com/search?q=validar+cpf+java). Apesar de ter sua utilidade, [regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: realmente testei aqui e deu certo dessa forma. Muito obrigada pela  explicação.

Comment: @Marin Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.